# IntelliJ doesn't focus when opening files

Tags: intellij-idea

On my machine, IntelliJ is set to the default app to open a few different types of files. XML being one of them.

However, when I have IntelliJ open, and another window is appearing on top of it, be it a browser or what ever, and I'm using window explorer to navigate to a an xml file, then proceed to double click the file, one would assume the IDE would come into focus with that file open. Instead, IntelliJ opens the file but doesn't focus. I need manually maximize the program every time for this. Is there a setting somewhere to change this functionality? I would like the program to come into focus when I open a file type that it's associated with.

Version:
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2
Build #IC-162.1121.32, built on July 9, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b216 x86
JVM: OpenJDK Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Windows 10 fresh install.

Comment: Is this normal? Am I being weird for expecting this functionality?